# Webpack require cross bundle (require another webpack bundle)

Tags: webpack, bundle, require

Background story: suppose there are 2 teams,  one team is working on main page, and the other team is working on a important component in this page.  when landing the main page, it will dynamically download the component script and run the js code(for landing performance).

the main page code is packaged as bundle.js and bundle1.js(bundle1.js is dynamic download by a require.ensure) by webpack,  the component code is packaged as component.js by webpack. SO, THE QUESTIONS IS : can the component.js code require the webpack module in bundle1.js